# suma de valores con jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

tengo una tabla la cual necesito sumar sus valores. lo puedo sumar la primera linea, las demas se suman a la primera linea. osea, solo sumo la primera linea.
necesito que la suma se realice en cada campo por separado. 
gracias por la ayuda.
aqui les dejo mi html, jquery y  php donde recibo los datos

```html
  function sumar() {

     var suma = 0;
     //llamamos la clase notas
      //$('.notas2').each(function() {
        $('form').find('.notas2').each(function() {
       if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
         suma += 0;
       } else {
         suma += parseFloat($(this).val());
       }
     });

     //alert(total);
     document.getElementById('sumaTotal').innerHTML = suma;
   }
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered  table-condensed table-hover" id="tablaRegistro">
   
   <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>P1</th>
    <th>P2</th>
    <th>P3</th>
    <th>P4</th>
    <th class='valores' scope="row">Suma</th>
    <th>%Promedio</th>
$cont=1;
  while ($registroAsistencia =mysqli_fetch_row($consulta_tabla_estudiante))
  {
$id=$registroAsistencia[0];

<tr>
 <!--llamamos el id, nombre y apaellido de la bd-->
        echo "<td><input type='text' class='notas2 form-control input-sm input' size='1px' name='notas[$id]'  id='p1' onChange='sumar();'></td>
   <td><input type='text' class='notas2 form-control input-sm input' size='1' name='notas[$id]' id='p2'  onChange='sumar();'></td>
   <td><input type='text' class='notas2 form-control input-sm input' size='1' name='notas[$id]' id='p3'  onChange='sumar();'></td> 
   <td><input type='text' class='notas2 form-control input-sm input' size='1' name='notas[$id]' id='p4' onChange='sumar();'></td>
     <td><span id='sumaTotal' size='1' class='sumaTotal'><input type='text' id='sumaTotal' name='sumaTotal' size='1' class='form-control input-sm input' readonly=''><span></td>
     <td><span id='promedio'><input type='text' id='promedio' name='promedio' size='1' class='form-control input-sm input' readonly=''><span></td>
}
 <button class='btn btn-success' data-target='bEnviar' value="bEnviar" name="bEnviar" id="bEnviar" onclick="porcentaje();">GUARDAR</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido solucionarlo modificando el JQuery:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){

var suma = 0;
$('.notas2').on('change', function(){

var id = $(this).data('id');
  $( ".group_"+id ).each(function() {

    console.log('value='+$(this).val());
     if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
       suma += 0;

     } else {
       suma += parseFloat($(this).val());
     }
     $('#sumaTotal_'+id).val(suma);
  });


});


});
</script>
<table class="table table-bordered  table-condensed table-hover" id="tablaRegistro">

            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>P1</th>
                <th>P2</th>
                <th>P3</th>
                <th>P4</th>
                <th class='valores' scope="row">Suma</th>
                <th>%Promedio</th>
<?php

for ($n=0;$n<=10;$n++) {


 ?>
<tr>

</tr>
      <td><input type='text' class='notas2 group_<?php echo $n;?> form-control input-sm input' size='1px' name='notas[$id]'     id='p1' data-id="<?php echo $n;?>" value=''></td>
            <td><input type='text' class='notas2 group_<?php echo $n;?> form-control input-sm input' size='1' name='notas[$id]' id='p2'   data-id="<?php echo $n;?>" value=''></td>
            <td><input type='text' class='notas2 group_<?php echo $n;?> form-control input-sm input' size='1' name='notas[$id]' id='p3'   data-id="<?php echo $n;?>" value=''></td>
            <td><input type='text' class='notas2 group_<?php echo $n;?> form-control input-sm input' size='1' name='notas[$id]' id='p4' data-id="<?php echo $n;?>" value=''></td>
                    <td><span id='sumaTotal_x' size='1' class='sumaTotal'><input type='text' id='sumaTotal<?php echo "_".$n;?>' name='sumaTotal' size='1' class='form-control input-sm input' readonly=''><span></td>
                    <td><span id='promedio'><input type='text' id='promedio' name='promedio' size='1' class='form-control input-sm input' readonly=''><span></td>

</tr>
<?php

}
 ?>
    <button class='btn btn-success' data-target='bEnviar' value="bEnviar" name="bEnviar" id="bEnviar" onclick="porcentaje();">GUARDAR</button>
```

He simulado la carga de la base de datos con un `for`

Comment: saludos Eduard y gracias por responder, lo agregue igual pero no me funciona. la consola no muestra error.

Comment: He modificado el ejemplo, simulando la carga de datos con un `for` en vez de un a BBDD. Esta vez lo he testado y si funciona. Pruebalo a ver.